# ASP.NET Identity , two step registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to implement two step registration, with 1st step being the user providing basic information and getting a token to confirm the email before registration is done, and the 2nd step taking the 1st step information, validating the token, and allowing the user in case of a valid token to set the password.

The issue is that this method `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` which is called in the 1st step expects an already existing user, which at this point it does not exist, it will be created in the 2nd step.

Is there any other option available ?

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("submit-registration-request")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> _1stStepRegistration([FromBody] UserRegistrationModel request)
    {
        if (await _userManager.Users.AnyAsync(user => user.Email == request.Email)) return BadRequest();

        /// => throws value cannot be null exteion ?????????? 
        ///
        string token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(
            new IamUser
            {
                Email = request.Email,
                PhoneNumber = request.Phone,

                Account = request.Account,

                UserName = $"{request.FirstName}.{request.LastName}",
            });
```

Comment: You could make the two-step process all in a single page, but use client scripting to make it feel like it's two separate pages.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, can you provide some details or maybe if  you know how to do it a link to some resource ? Currently I'm using a react app with two forms, one is the initial form in which I'm providing basic user info, and this makes a requst to the action I've presented, and the 2nd component is another react page which will extract this basic info provided in the 1st form from some url and continue the registration process

Comment: In the "from some url" add the new user's username along with the token you got back as query parameters. In the second step find the user, then use usermanager to add password.